Programatically select an option from a Primevue Select element
I have a Primevue Select element in my Nuxt3/Vue3 app.
I want to change the selected option programatically, but I can't find information on how to do that.  There is not ".value" I can set.
This is my element:
              <Select id="Gage" v-model="selectedGageValue" filter :options="getGageOptionsList" optionLabel="name"
            optionValue="description" placeholder=" ... " :virtualScrollerOptions="{ itemSize: 50 }"
            @change="onGageSelectionChange" class=""></Select>


can you give more details?  what are the options and in what situation do you want to set the Select programmatically, i.e. what should trigger the selection?  the selected option being held by the v-model selectedGageValue should mean you just need to update selectedGageValue however/whenever you like.

You have the following code:
<Select id="Gage" v-model="selectedGageValue" filter :options="getGageOptionsList" optionLabel="name"
        optionValue="description" placeholder=" ... " :virtualScrollerOptions="{ itemSize: 50 }"
        @change="onGageSelectionChange" class=""></Select>

Looking at your component I can predict that your getGageOptionsList has some value like this:
getGageOptionsList: [ { name: 'Option1', description: 'Option1 description'}, { name: 'Option2', description: 'Option2 description'} ]

When you are using the property optionValue from the Select component, the component will put the description value inside your v-mode selectedGageValue
So, to select it you'll need to set the description value to the selectedGageValue, like this:
this.selectedGageValue = 'Option2 description' //this will select the second option

It will work, BUT that's not the correct way to do that, because isn't common to use a long string as identifier. Here are some better ways to approach it
First Method - Change your Select component and remove the optionValue, this way you will let the PrimeVue know you want the full array value eg: { name: 'Option1', description: 'Option1 description'} as optionValue.
<Select id="Gage" v-model="selectedGageValue" filter :options="getGageOptionsList" optionLabel="name"
    placeholder=" ... " :virtualScrollerOptions="{ itemSize: 50 }"
    @change="onGageSelectionChange" class=""></Select>

Now you need to set the entire value from the key stored in getGageOptionsList you want. eg:
this.selectedGageValue = this.getGageOptionsList[1] //it will programatically select the second option

Second Method - Change your Select component and edit the optionValue to a simpler property like 'id' and add it to your options, like this:
getGageOptionsList: [ { id:0, name: 'Option1', description: 'Option1 description'}, { id:1, name: 'Option2', description: 'Option2 description'} ]

now, change your component:
<Select id="Gage" v-model="selectedGageValue" filter :options="getGageOptionsList" optionLabel="name"
    optionValue="id" placeholder=" ... " :virtualScrollerOptions="{ itemSize: 50 }"
    @change="onGageSelectionChange" class=""></Select>

and select programatically the id
this.selectedGageValue = 1 //this will select the second option

